# how to use delegates with Automatic Reference Counting

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I've jumped on the ARC bandwagon. In the past I would have my delegate properties declared like this:

```
@property(assign) id<MyProtocol> delegate;
```

So I thought I would do this under ARC:

```
@property(weak) id<MyProtocol> delegate;
```

Not so. On the @synthesize statement in the .m I have a compile **error**:

*Semantic Issue: Existing ivar 'delegate' for __weak property 'delegate' must be __weak*

I HAVE declared it as weak though! Also how do I pass a class implementing a protocol to a weakly referenced property. Do I have to wrap it in one of those weird obj_unretained calls?

Any help on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: ARC can be discussed publicly.  iOS 5 specific API cannot.

Comment: The implication is that iOS 5 supports GC Obj-C, which is presumably confidential unless Apple's announced it (I don't know if they have; I've been too busy to keep up).

Answer (score 65, accepted):

"ivar" means "instance variable", which you have not shown. I'm betting it looks something like this:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
    id delegate;
}

@property (weak) id delegate;
```

What the error is saying is that it must look like this:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject {
    __weak id delegate;
}

@property (weak) id delegate;
```

If the property claims to be weak, the ivar that the value ends up being stored in must be weak as well.

Comment: Or you could just remove the ivar altogether and let the `@synthesize` line handle that for you as well. :)

Comment: your assumption was correct. And DaveDelong - are you telling me that for 1.5 years I've been writing iOS with ivars in the header as well as the @property declaration and I don't need ivar when I synthesize?! this is amazing lol! Thankyou!

Comment: @Mike don't feel to bad.  The ability to do that sort of accreted across architectures and couplers in the last year+.  It is now complete, though.

Comment: However, if an ivar is not declared it will not be visible in Xcode. (bug filed).

Comment: Adding _weak before id in my ivar declaration gives me the error: "Unknown type name "_weak".
Kudos to anyone who respond to this so late in the the game (:

Comment: @Dylan: You need two underscores.

Comment: But the answer does not work for a 10.6 target build:  "The current deployment target does not support automated weak references"  Syntax torn between two OS revisions :(

Comment: @ctpenrose: If you still need to support pre-10.7/5.0, you should be using something like `{ __unsafe_unretained id foo; } @property(assign) id foo;`. You could cook up some `#define`s and build different versions, but then you'd need to test both of them. Alternatively, there's a possibility that someone will add runtime support to 10.5/10.6, just as they did with "blocks" (whether the compiler will let you use it is another matter entirely).

Comment: I've found out since if anyway is interested that not declaring the ivars means you can't look at the values in when debugging.

Comment: @MitchR: That's a bug in GCC/GDB (one doesn't generate debug symbols, perhaps?). I get around it by simply calling the getter method.

Comment: ( nonatomic , strong ) is also good options.. it works for me.