# how to pass value when popToRoot

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

will like to know how do i pass value back to the root view controller when i popToRoot.

```
introVideoViewController *intro = [introVideoViewController alloc];
    intro.fromReset =1;
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Comment: learn to use delegation ... it will be very helpful.

Comment: Since when does delegation not work?!

Comment: Entire iPhone sdk is based on delegation ... how can you say it doesn't work with ios5... any written proof you can guide me tooo..? @AalokParikh

Comment: but it not working like it works with ios4

Comment: @AalokParikh Delegation still works but in slightly different manner see here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529191/how-to-use-delegates-with-automatic-reference-counting

Comment: Certainly does - maybe you could post a question about it with some code, & someone might be able to see what you're doing wrong

Comment: ok thanks for the answer i have been misguided sorry for the before comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the VC that you want to pop back from, you need to give it a delegate property -

```
@class MyViewController;

@protocol MyViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

    -(void)myViewControllerDidDismiss:(MyViewController *)controller withSomeObject:(id)someObject;

@end


@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyViewControllerDelegate> myViewControllerDelegate;

@end
```

...and in the root VC you make it conform to that protocol, and implement the dismiss method -

```
-(void)myViewControllerDidDismiss:(MyViewController *)controller withSomeObject:(id)someObject {

    // now I've got the object from the VC I just popped

}
```

Forgot to mention that you need to call myViewControllerDidDismiss:withSomeObject: when you pop the VC.

Edit - Also forgot to mention that you need to set the VC's delegate as your root VC when you create it, or else it'll be trying to call nil when you pop back -

```
[myViewController setMyViewControllerDelegate:self];
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use the below code

```
NSArray *arr = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
CLASS_OF_ROOT_VIEW_CONTROLLER *rvc = (CLASS_OF_ROOT_VIEW_CONTROLLER *)[arr objectAtIndex:0];
rvc.variable = value;
```